# Using Ping to find out if DB Connection is alive in Golang

Tags: go

Is it safe to just ping the database to check if my golang app is still connected or is there a better solution than this? I've read somewhere that we should not use .ping() to determine a connection loss.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say Ping() is the way to do it if you need to test the connection separate of running queries probably at program start only.

Normally I just trust in the fact that database/sql will automatically try to reconnect in case if you are executing queries against DB and connection fails. So you could just use Open to check DB connection args are correct and trust query to return an error in case connection is lost.

People say Ping() can cause race conditions but cannot demonstrate me how or provide a suitable alternative where connection test needed.

This is how Gorm (widely used Golang ORM project) does it:

```
// Send a ping to make sure the database connection is alive.
    if d, ok := dbSQL.(*sql.DB); ok {
        if err = d.Ping(); err != nil {
            d.Close()
        }
    }
    return
```

https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm

Comment: Why shouldn't one write a query to list all tables? Wouldn't that be better than ping?

Comment: @sofs1 Ping is faster

Answer (score 8):

Probably better to execute a simple query and check the result. The Ping() method is safe to use, but is optional to implement by database drivers.

See [Ping()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Pinger)

Comment: Ping also creates a new connection everytime in my case :(

Comment: Ping, like other calls that reach the database, might create a new connection if no available connections exist. It depends on the implementation of your program and the driver. Go maintains a pool of connections and will reuse connections if possible. See [connection pooling](http://go-database-sql.org/connection-pool.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can ping the database, test it, close the connection, and test it again. Example:

`database.go`

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "database/sql"
    _ "modernc.org/sqlite"
)

func sqliteConnect() (sqliteDB *sql.DB) {
    // driver and data source names
    sqliteDB, err := sql.Open("sqlite", "./localdatabase.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot connect to sqlite DB: %v", err)
    }

    return sqliteDB
}
```

`database_test.go`

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSqliteConnect(t *testing.T) {
    db := sqliteConnect()
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(0)

    t.Run("Ping database", func(t *testing.T) {
        if db.Ping() != nil {
            t.Errorf("Unable to ping sqlite database ... %v", db.Ping())
        }
    })

    db.Close()

    t.Run("Check Connections", func(t *testing.T) {
        if db.Stats().OpenConnections != 0 {
            t.Errorf("Unable to close database connections ... %v", db.Stats().OpenConnections)
        }
    })
}
```